# Is it normal for sprinkler heads to be a few inches under the soil level?

Tags: sprinkler-system

We bought a house with a 7-zone sprinkler system, and I'm currently inspecting and updating sprinkler heads.  Some of the rotors are installed really low, a few inches under the ground.  Is this normal, or would it be a good idea to raise them with short pipes?

Comment: are. they the pop up kind

Comment: Yes.  And they do pop up above ground and seem to "work fine" in general.

Comment: I meant these "pipes": https://www.amazon.com/Orbit-37056-Cut-Off-Riser-4-Inch/dp/B00L2L1ZUA

I already raised a couple of heads with them.

Comment: They'll do, but I prefer less plastic on the planet and more pennies in my bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the head will be flush with the soil. This prevents the popup action from being impeded by soil and lawn thatch. They can end up low due to settling,  grading after installation, or simply lawn growth.

You wouldn't have to raise them with pipes. You could just surgically excavate the area and lift the head and its supply as needed, then backfill to support it and replace the turf. If you do it right you won't even see the scar.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  I bought a set of 3/4" x 4" risers with the goal of lifting the heads, but got doubts as the lawn looked perfect with invisible sprinklers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is common for the sprinkler system to gradually sink into the ground. Then the spray heads or "popup" sprinkler heads to need to be raised.  Doing this is relatively easy.

Unscrew the head and remove it.

Look at the bottom. Most will have a 1/2 npt or 3/4 npt female end.

If you are looking at a male threaded end, you are most likely looking at the sprinkler head with the installation nipple attached. That needs to be unscrewed from the head.

This [Nipple](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZG6NP7) is what you need to replace with a longer part.  If the head is an inch below the ground, ( NOT THE GRASS.) then you need a nipple about an inch longer.  Note:  nipples are sold in certain increments.  You will not get any thing like a  1 3/4" nipple.  So you have to buy what will be the closest to what you need without raising the head so high you mow it off.
You may be tempted to by a "cutoff" nipple.  These require you to cut fairly precisely to the length you need.  If you are good at measurements and good at cutting things square, this could be good for you.

You may be looking at the spray head with what looks like a nipple with a female end.  This is a [Riser](https://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/orbit-plastic-riser-extension-3-4-in-x-4-in-fnpt-x-mnpt-37056?gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwyqWkBhBMEiwAp2yUFgya4YiB84KP2pGetkJn7g9hUXkeogek_XSKvoZbT1cmruwaDaH3PBoCGRoQAvD_BwE). It is like a nipple but has one female an one male end.  These are available in different lengths as well, but not such a variety. Cut off versions are also available.

Now that you know what you need, you will have to remove the riser or nipple from the spray head. OR from the irrigation pipe in the ground.  ( Look in the hole the spray head was in.) Sometimes this can be difficult to remove. There is a special tool (an extractor) that is made to do this. Or sometimes just some needle nose pliers will work.  Don't worry about ruining threads, these parts are cheep and can be thrown away.

Install the new nipple or riser.

Now the fun part.  But very important.  You need a piece of tubing or hose that will fit over the nipple or riser. Something flexable so you can direct the water out and away from the hole.  Place your tubing. turn on the zone for a few seconds.  This is to flush away and dirt or grass or debris that got in the pipe or nipple.  **If you don't clean out the line you risk getting the debris in the spray head screen and degrading performance.**

Screw the spray head back on. Adjust for the aim and spray angle and test.

After you do one you know the drill and are almost as good as the experts.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you.  That's more or less what I figured, and your Riser link is exactly what I bought.  I don't think I can use a nipple, because I've got an elbow in the bottom; I need a female end to screw over it.  I had doubts about the low heads because they looked and worked fine, and I thought that maybe they had been installed that way on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Excavate carefully around one popup.

If it was installed to a good standard, you may find a double elbow at the base, and a short length of pipe (nearly horizontal) going to the feeder pipe, attached by another elbow.  If you are this lucky, everything can swivel at the elbows. Lift the popup and replace the dirt.

Comment: "Excavate" and "carefully" do not compile, especially when I do it.  I understand what you are saying, but for me installing a short riser is faster and less destructive for the lawn.  Thanks anyway.